# "undefined" return instead of name of game

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, http-post

Currently I have a web page that users can title and create new "games" . What should happen is a user enters the name into a text box, hits "create" then the game is created. Currently when the user hits create , the GUID is generated an the game is created. If the user named the  game Test, it should display, Game: Test Remove( clicking remove removes the game.) However the game is listed as , Game: undefined Remove. How can i make it so that the name the user give the game is displayed? 
Thank you for your help

Here is my code

Controller

```
using PlanningPoker.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace PlanningPoker.Controllers {
public class GMController : ApiController {
    private static List<Game> games = new List<Game>() {
            new Game() {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Title = "D&D"
            }
        };

    [Route("data/games")]
    public IEnumerable<Game> GetAllGames() {
        return games;
    }

    [Route("data/games/create"), HttpPost]
    public Guid CreateGame(string title) {
        Game g = new Game() {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Title = title
        };

        games.Add(g);

        return g.ID;
    }


    [Route("data/games/remove"), HttpPost]
    public void RemoveGame(Guid id) {
        games.RemoveAll(g => g.ID == id);
    }
 }
}
```

Index (hmtl) (users can create games here, created games are displayed here)

```
<head>
<title>Planning Poker</title>
<style>
    .inlinetext {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/GameSVC.js"></script>
<script src="Gamelist.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#button').on('click', function (data) {
            svc.Game.Add($('#testtxt').val(), function (d) { console.log(d), window.location.reload(); });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>



<body>
<h3 class='inlinetext'> Create Game: </h3>
    <input type="text" id="testtext" name="ime">
    <button id="button" >Create</button>

<h4>Games</h4>

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data:$data.games, as:'$game' }">
    <li>
        Game :
        <span data-bind="text: $game.Title"> </span>
        <a data-bind="click: function(d,e) { $parent.removeGame(d); }">Remove</a>
    </li>
</ul>


</body>

 </html>
```

Gamelist (js)

```
function AppViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.games = ko.observableArray([]);

$.getJSON("/data/games", function (d) {
    self.games(d);
});


self.removeGame = function (game) {

    svc.Game.Remove(game.ID, function () {
       $.getJSON("/data/games", function (d) {
            self.games(d);
        });
    });
}

}
$(function () {
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
```

Game SVC

```
var svc = svc || {
Game: {
    Add: function (title, cb) {
        $.post('data/games/create/?title='+title, cb);
    },
    Remove: function (id, cb) {
        $.post("data/games/remove/?id=" + encodeURIComponent(id), cb);
    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use knockout for the whole form and not a combination of jQuery and knockout.

You can add a Game to your model which will be an observable which is then added to the games observableArray when create is clicked. It is then set to a new Game.

There is no need to use the code that you are using on the click binding. By default the current object in the foreach will be passed to your click function.

Another thing is if you are using rest you should actually be using the verbs for different things such as "DELETE" for deleting an item. http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html. To do this you would need to change your webapi. My example below uses the rest verbs.

```
<body>
    <!-- ko with: game -->
    <h3 class='inlinetext'> Create Game: </h3>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: Title">
        <button data-bind="click: $root.addGame">Create</button>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <h4>Games</h4>

    <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: games}">
        <li>
            Game :
            <span data-bind="text: Title"> </span>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeGame">Remove</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

var AppViewModel = function ($) {
    var self = this;

    self.games = ko.observableArray();

    $.getJSON("/data/games", function (games) {
        var mappedGames = $.map(games, function(game) { return new Game(game) });
        self.games(mappedGames);
    });

    self.addGame = function (game) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/data/games/',
            type: "PUT",
            data: ko.toJSON(game),
            success: function (id) {
                game.ID = id;
                self.games.push(game);
                self.game(new Game());
            }
        });
    };

    self.removeGame = function (game) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/data/games/' + game.ID,
            type: "DELETE",
            success: function (id) {
                self.games.remove(game);
            }
        });
    };

    self.game = ko.observable(new Game());
};

var Game = function (game) {
    var self  = this;

    self.ID = undefined;
    self.Title = ko.observable();

    //initilize game
    if (game) {
        self.ID = game.ID;
        self.Title(game.Title);
    }
};
```

Here's a demo where I mocked out jquery to test it:

http://jsfiddle.net/mq8Us/2/

Comment: This is great! How would i go about changing the web api to allow this?

Comment: If you are using WebAPI 2 you can name the methods as the HTTP Verb. ie Delete() will work for DELETE. Please accept the answer if you are happy with it.